# Chrome element inspector only displays visual dimensions if the element has a "class"

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

I'm guessing this is because of an update because I feel I would have noticed this before, but when I use Chrome's element inspector it only highlights the dimensions of an element if that element has a specified *class*. If the element has an *id* and no *class*, no dimensions are given.

Highlighting element with class...

[image: highlight element with class]

Highlighting element without class...

[image]

The second image shows the lack of yellow dimensions box. Obviously this isn't the biggest deal but I'd like to know if this is a bug or if Chrome is doing this for a specific reason and if there is a way to change it.